# How can I reduce variance in program performance caused by instruction cache?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang

I'm working on optimizing a program and at the point where trivial changes in the code (e.g. adding a if-else branch that never gets run) will cause 2-3% variance in code performance and I have reason to believe that the cause is that the extra assembly moves hot functions around cache lines changes the performance characteristics of the program due to the instruction cache. This makes it really difficult to measure optimizations that make the code 1% faster.

Do you have any suggestions on how I could minimize that variance while profiling?

For example, any clang/gcc flags that add a lot of padding in-between functions and align them to cache lines?

Comment: Are you sure, this is due to instruction cache and not because that if / else statement prevents some compiler optimizations. Have you compared the relevant parts of the assembler code? Also I don't know if adding padding will help you, because this makes the effects of other changes non-representable for the actual application.

Comment: Show the minimal amount of code.

Comment: Which processor?  Your getting down to specifics or specializations that are not common to all breeds of processors.

Comment: "measure optimizations that make the code 1% faster" sounds desperate.

Comment: @Dieter: Well, it can be relevant if you are working on a critical piece of code fot Google or Facebook... But I agree.

Comment: @MikeMB I don't think so, but I only briefly looked at the possible effects of branch prediction. Good idea, I should examine it more. As for padding, I'm hoping that different optimizations will improve performance mostly independently of each other (otherwise there'd be no end to it).

Comment: @DieterLücking Salami slices - 1% optimization pile up and for core infra code, it's a 1% optimization over the whole system. In general though, I'd agree it's not worth focusing on.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Any good readings where I could educate myself on those differences?

Comment: I never had to optimize my code on that level, so this is just theory, but by introducing padding in the instruction cache (NOPs?) you are creating an artificial bottleneck there. So the effect of other optimizations might become less visible - or you might not realize, that something you did might actually decrease the performance in the actual code.